# Extracting most common word using WordCloud but it extracts the most common letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-cloud

I'm trying to extract the most common words using a Wordcloud, but instead i'm getting the most common letters. Here's my code:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud

stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
QUEER_VOICES = dataset[dataset['categoryId'] == 0]
QUEER_VOICES = QUEER_VOICES['short_description']
RELIGION = dataset[dataset['categoryId'] == 1]
RELIGION = RELIGION['short_description']

def wordcloud_draw(dataset, color = 'white'):
    words = ' '.join(str(dataset))
    cleaned_word = ' '.join([word for word in words.split() if (word != 'news' and word != 'text')])
    wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords = stop, background_color = "white", width = 2500, height = 2500).generate(cleaned_word)

    plt.figure(1, figsize = (10,7))
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()

print("QUEER VOICES related words:")
wordcloud_draw(QUEER_VOICES, 'white')
print("RELIGION related words:")
wordcloud_draw(RELIGION, 'white')
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe some example of the date would be useful to us to help you, but i'm pretty sure the problem is in `' '.join([word for word in words.split() if (word != 'news' and word != 'text')])`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I found the error thanks to you.